# Showing WMTS layer above largest scale in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, scale, wmts

When zooming in on a WMTS layer, the layer disappears at a set large scale. Does QGIS have the ability to show the last scale available when zoomed in further?

I can see it expanded at the new scale before it disappears.

For example, the layer is visible at 1:10000. At 1:9000 it is gone. I'd like to see the layer even if it is pixelated. Am I missing an option somewhere?

Comment: You  could use the XYZ Tiles in the processing toolbox to make your own tile map to the zoom level you require.  That is what I did.  https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#generate-xyz-tiles-mbtiles  Then add the MBTiles file to your map - it will be big.

Comment: what does the capabilities document say - there may be a min/max scale setting on the server end

Comment: Overzoom by stretching the last available resolution would make sense if it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS does this by default in either direction (zoomed in or zoomed out further than the minimum or maximum scale of the WMTS).

Comment: If you are having issues with e.g. a MapProxy cache, make sure you check if your higher zoom levels actually contain tiles or if it might be blank because of that ;)